# Formatting of the caption of a chart

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting, charts

Does anyone of you know a way to format the caption of a chart in Crystal Reports? I have a number that stands for a specific year, this number is 4 digits long. I wnat the caption to be shown like:

> 2009

But the current way its shown is

> 2.009

EDIT:
The years are dynamically load from the database and in the DB they are stored as a datetime Field that i select by using the year function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about crystal reports. You should mention that in the question title, or at least in the question itself, not just in the tags.

I suppose you could use a real DateTime object (instead of an int) for the date and use some function to format dates to display only the year. Like [this guy](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/DateFormatInCR06132007092248AM/DateFormatInCR.aspx):

> For example, I need a date formatting as following:
>   23-Mar-2007
>   The following formula will do the trick:
>   ToText({MYFIELDNAME }, "dd-MMM-yyyy")

That relates to field names, but I suppose you can use the same function (ToText) for the caption of the chart?

You could also store the year in a string.